# Unable to skip reading few lines in pandas read_csv() function

Tags: python, pandas, csv, jupyter-notebook, data-science

Tried to skip reading a few lines from csv file using the on_bad_lines argument set to .
TypeError: read_csv() got an unexpected keyword argument 'on_bad_lines'. The documentation has this keyword but is throwing up this error.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[According to the docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas.read_csv), `on_bad_lines` was added in Pandas 1.4.0.

You're probably using an older version of Pandas.

Comment: Thank You, I checked this and the version is ```1.3.5```